# Adding Layout Weight dynamically

Tags: android-layout

For my project I want 30 images in my page, and I want to arrange them in such a way that there are 3 images in one horizontal linear layout.

Since I cannot use density pixels as it may look different on different divices, I want to use layout_weights. The way we write in our XML files :

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        **android:layout_weight="0.33"**
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I want to know what will be the Exact Equivalent of the XML code in Java Language..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the weight using the LayoutParams of your view (the last param)

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
myView.setLayoutParams(params);
```